# Is there a way to set the gutenberg color palette outside the theme?

Tags: block-editor, color-picker

Is there a away to set the gutenberg block-editor color palette other than in the theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to use the `init` hook if you want to use `add_theme_support` from a plugin. I've tested the below code as a plugin and worked for me.

```
<?php

/* Plugin name: Add Color Palette
*/
function mytheme_setup_theme_supported_features()
{
    add_theme_support('editor-color-palette', array(
        array(
            'name' => esc_attr__('Strong magenta', 'themeLangDomain'),
            'slug' => 'strong-magenta',
            'color' => '#a156b4',
        ),
    ));
}

add_action('init', 'mytheme_setup_theme_supported_features');
```

Please consider avoiding using `add_theme_support` outside the theme's functions.php file.

The official description for the `add_theme_support` :

> Must be called in the theme’s functions.php file to work. If attached
> to a hook, it must be ‘after_setup_theme’. The ‘init’ hook may be too
> late for some features.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/

Comment: So the docu says **not to use `init`** but `after_setup_theme`, still in your code you don't. Why?

Comment: Thanks for asking, `after_setup_theme` hook doesn't work from a plugin to add support for editor-color-palette.